# Is it fare for the cost of the "tag spag" problem to have a high price?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

I'm seeing some cases of tag spaghetti. Why might we need all of [costs](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/costs), [price](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/price), and [fares](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fares) as separate concepts?

- [costs](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/costs) is one of the synonyms of our old [budget](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/budget) tag along with [cheap](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheap), [deals](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deals), [shoestring](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shoestring), [discounts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discounts), and [no-costs](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-costs). This set of tags is explained as:

  > Questions about minimizing costs and expenditure when spending the least money is a high priority.

  Some of the main tags it's used together with include [air-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-travel), [accommodation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accommodation), [trains](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trains), [public-transport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-transport), [transportation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transportation), [planning](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning), and [tickets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tickets).
- [price](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/price) (36 questions) is explained as:

  > Questions regarding prices of various objects and services (not related to budgeting a trip).

  It's mainly used along with [air-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-travel), [tickets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tickets), and [budget](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/budget) tags.
- [fares](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fares) (40 questions) is explained as:

  > costs of transportation services, price at which a ticket is sold

  Mainly used along with [air-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-travel), [budget](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/budget), [tickets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tickets), [trains](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trains), and [bookings](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bookings).

Questions to ponder:

1. Should "costs" be a synonym of "price" instead?
2. "Price" is often used on questions about air travel or tickets, and as we know, the price of a plane ticket is called a "fare". Is this distinction too subtle for many of our non-native English users? Is it even important?
3. So should "fares" be made a synonym of the broader "price"?
4. Should some of us use more of our time to retag questions about ticket and transportation prices to remove "price" and add "fares"?

Any other points?

Comment: Rail fare would make sense to some, but I worry it's a very English term for it (I could be wrong).  But if they're asking about the price of a ... tour, or haircut (I think we've had those), or tango show, it seems wrong to have it as a synonym.

Comment: I'd be more in favour of retagging transportation ones as [tag:fares] and anything else (tour, hostels?) as [tag:price]

Comment: @MarkMayo: Great - when will you start and how vigilant will you be on this from now on? (-: Tags don't just curate themselves you know.

Comment: In my opinion `price` is not even a good tag. They either show up shopping questions or if looking for low prices the `budget` tag is sufficient. But that's just me.

Comment: sure, but we've not reached consensus yet :)  
So re [tag:price], for something like hostels where we can't use [tag:fare], what could we use instead? Always [tag:budget]?

Comment: Eg [Why is Diet Coke more expensive than regular Coca-Cola and other soft drinks in Indonesia?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34725/why-is-diet-coke-more-expensive-than-regular-coca-cola-and-other-soft-drinks-in) - budget doesn't seem applicable here.

Comment: As I suggested we could merge `fare` into `price` since a fare is just a price of a particular thing (ticket). But do we even need `price`? Isn't it a bit of a meta tag? What kind of questions would benefit from `price` and no other tag, the test Joel gives for deciding whether a tag is any good. Prices fluctuate anyway. I don't think curiosity questions are good bases for growing our tag forest. Find some good non-curiosity questions to make such points.

Comment: I lay back and thought about it for a minute. I still think fares are distinct from other types, and so am leaning towards changing price questions to costs, as you suggested. We'd still need it as a synonym though. Will wait and see what others' thoughts are.

Comment: [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) (Blog. 08-06-10 by Jeff Atwood) ... [How do I correctly tag my questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878) (Meta)

Comment: Don't forget we would then need to move `costs` out from the synonyms of `budget`.

Comment: Dammit....stupid budgets...

Answer (score 1):

How about unifying them all into a single tag: [price](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/price), which also covers [fares](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fares) and [costs](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/costs). We'll remove [costs](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/costs) synonym to [budget](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/budget) and make it a synonym together with [fares](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fares) to [prices](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prices) instead.

Comment: I don't think `fares-and-prices` is ugly but since a fare is one kind of price it's a bit like `cars-and-vehicles` or `dogs-and-animals` or `hostels-and-accommodation`.

Comment: @hippietrail: I see what you mean. I guess [tag:price] should be sufficient, with the remaining listed as synonyms.

Comment: I strongly vote to keep [tag:fares] separate.

Comment: I strongly wonder why. Is it based on "they're different words" or can you point out something in the tagging help, meta posts, or blog?

Comment: @mindcorrosive Most people mention train fare, bus fare, and similar. Prices differ from fare by usage. In common usage fare is used to denote the money we are charged while using a service but price is commonly used to denote the cost of something we buy.

Comment: @kolappankols: Your definition of "fare" here is wrong. See my reply under [your answer](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/a/1895/140).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that price can be unified with costs keeping fares seperate.

Prices differ from fare by usage. In common usage fare is used to denote the money we are charged while using a transport service but price is commonly used to denote the cost of something we buy.

Comment: I understand that, but from practical perspective, the distinction doesn't matter. Most of our users (particularly those with maternal language other than English) will use predominantly `price` when they really mean `fare', since they associate both with "money I pay for X". If you don't believe me, see the questions tagged [tag:price]. Tagging shouldn't to be semantically perfect, it should first and foremost be useful.

Comment: @mindcorrosive Yes, you are right about the tagging. Most of the people are using price instead of fares. But using same tag for both purposes may confuse some users.

Comment: This is not true in my experience: "fare is used to denote the money we are charged while using a service". Almost all services would use the generic terms "price", "cost", etc. "Fare" is specifically the price of transportation, which is the same as the price of a ticket to go somewhere. Other kinds of tickets (concert, museum, zoo, etc) would sometimes use "cover" but usually just "price", "cost", etc.

Comment: @hippietrail Yes, I found that in wiki "A fare is the fee paid by a passenger for use of a public transport system: rail, bus, taxi, etc. In the case of air transport, the term airfare is often used". However it's easy to dentote it as busfare rather than using cost of bus tickets. I suggest to keep the fare tag seperate.